# Is it possible to write a unit test for the method that has, 1)Return type void, 2)access specifier private or protected?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, nunit

Is it possible to write Nunit framework unit test for a class that have a method with void return type and access specifier protected or private in classic asp.net. Let me clear as because Im beginner in unit testing.

Update:This is my void function in case means, how can I write the unit test for this?

```
        public void function(TextBox txtBox, string Result)
        {
            if (Result.Trim().ToString() == "&nbsp;")
            {
                txtBox.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                txtBox.Text = Result;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yes it is possible to do both, however some argue that you should not unit test private and protected methods directly as they should be covered by your tests of public methods and properties.

Comment: @Ben Would you please gie me some example or reference site for this scenario?

Comment: Can you add a small example of the class you want to unittest?

Comment: What behaviour do you want to check has occurred after the void method has been called? Unit testing is about testing a unit. this does not mean (necessarily) individual private functions in a class. Private method organisation is an implementation detail that your tests should not care about. You tests should care about testing the behaviour of your unit, not its internal implmentation

Comment: @rene I updated my question with example scenario for unit test with void return type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're asking 2 questions:

*Is it possible to write Nunit framework unit test for a class that have a method with void return type?* It is possible, but in some way you have to know that everything went fine during execution of the method. For example, if it throws an exception, the test is failed, otherwise it is considered to be succeeded. Furthermore, you can check other properties if the side effect of the method has changed these properties.

*Is it possible to write Nunit framework unit test for a class with access specifier protected or private in classic asp.net?* It is not common practise to unit test private and protected members. However, if you need it, it can be done by reflection, but you can also use `internal` instead of private. In the AssemblyInfo.cs, use `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute like this:

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("UnitTestAssembly")]
```

Only the UnitTestAssembly classes can access the internal members. The members stay hidden for other classes. UnitTestAssembly must be the name of your unit test project/assembly. This does not work when the assembly is strong named; in that case you have to specify more. [This link](http://weblogs.asp.net/bhouse/using-internalsvisibleto-attribute-with-strong-named-assemblies) might help you in that case.

*Update:...how can I write the unit test for this?* Declare an internal function in the class where also `function` is defined:

```
    internal string GetTextboxText(Textbox txtBox)
    {
        return txtBox.Text;
    }
```

Now you can write unit tests:

```
  ...
  yourClassInstance.function(myTxtBox, "SomeString");
  Assert.IsTrue(yourClassInstance.GetTextboxText(myTxtBox) == "SomeString");
  ...
  yourClassInstance.function(myTxtBox, "&nbsp;");
  Assert.IsTrue(yourClassInstance.GetTextboxText(myTxtBox) == "");
```

But what happens when you specify a null textbox?

```
  yourClassInstance.function(null, "&nbsp;"); // Will probably throw exception
  Assert.IsTrue(yourClassInstance.GetTextboxText(myTxtBox) == "");
```

How must this be handled? That is what you can verify in your unit test.